# Create an array form different array with unknown amount of data and filter blank data array

Tags: php, arrays

I have three different array, some may contain data, some not. each array can contain unknown amount of data. So first i want to check for data amount in every array and then create another array called 'profession' with first value of three array, second value of three array and so on. if some contain empty value in both three field I want to filter it.

This is my code and can't figure it out where i am wrong.

```
 <?php

$org= array('', 10,11);
$suborg = array(11,12,13);
$desg = array('','',7);
$data = array();
if (is_array($org)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($org as $key) {
        $data['orgs'][$i] = $key;
        $i++;
 }
    if (is_array($suborg)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($suborg as $key) {
            $data['sorg'][$i] = $key;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    if (is_array($desg)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($desg as $key) {
            $data['desg'][$i] = $key;
            $i++;
        }
    }

    foreach ($data as $row => $value){
        $i = 0;
        $profession = array();
        $profession['fld_org_id'] = (isset($value[$i]) ? $value[$i] : '');
        $profession['fld_suborg_id'] =  (isset($value[$i]) ? $value[$i] : '');
        $profession['fld_desg_id'] = (isset($value[$i]) ? $value[$i] : '');
        var_dump($profession);
        echo "<br>";
        if($profession['fld_org_id'] != '' || $profession['fld_suborg_id'] != '' ||  $profession['fld_desg_id'] != '') {

            echo 'Profession Inserted';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Actually I am wanting result like

```
$profession('','11','');
$profession('10','12','');
$profession('11','13','7');
```

and if `$profession('','','')`, I want to remove it.

Comment: What is the exact problem, how does the result differ from what you need?

Comment: @jeroen my exact problem is "User may have multiple profession and every profession have organization name, sub org name and designation , Many time some organizaion dont have sub organization and some time a person have designation without any organizaion"

Comment: In last foreach , $i always equal zero

Comment: @JOELEE yes, how could i overcome it?

Comment: @aziz see my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to basically put into a columned storing. Independent of the number of values in `$org`, `$suborg` and  `$desg`? If so, you have to loop based on the number of values the reference array have (I have not implemented a functionality to check which array has the most number of values, I just used the `$org` as reference).

So to accomplish this, you have to first keep in mind the number of values you want to fetch from the subarrays, and then loop through the data array. I also use the $row (key-name) to build the new `fld_org_id` (and equals) keys with the corresponding value.

```
<?php
//Added two more values in each array, including one that should not be kept (the last one)
$org= array('', 10,11, 1, '');
$suborg = array(11,12,13, 1, '');
$desg = array('','',7, 1, ''); 
$data = array();
if (is_array($org) && is_array($suborg) && is_array($desg)) {
    $data['org'] = $org;
    $data['sorg'] = $suborg;
    $data['desg'] = $desg;
    $numberOfColumns = count($data['org']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfColumns; $i++){
        $profession = array();
        //Loop through data-array.
        foreach ($data as $row => $value){
           $profession['fld_'.$row.'_id'] = (isset($value[$i]) ? $value[$i] : '');
        }
        //If one of all values in array, do whatever you want to keep it
        if(count(array_filter($profession, function($v){ return $v != ""; })) > 0){
           echo "Keeping this<br/>";
        }else{
           echo "NOT keeping this<br/>";
        }
        var_dump($profession);
        echo "<br>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$data = array_filter(array_map(null,  $desg, $suborg, $org), 'implode');
```

This is achievable due to two [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) properties:

> Usually when using two or more arrays, they should be of equal length
>   because the callback function is applied in parallel to the
>   corresponding elements. If the arrays are of unequal length, shorter
>   ones will be extended with empty elements to match the length of the
>   longest.
>
> An interesting use of this function is to construct an array of
>   arrays, which can be easily performed by using NULL as the name of the
>   callback function

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/958308a9abef5042a7ced2841ba6f3cd7f59363f).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$org= array('', 10,11);
$suborg = array(11,12,13);
$desg = array('','',7);
$data = array();

$isVaild = is_array($org) && is_array($suborg) && is_array($desg);

if($isVaild){

    $profession = array(
        'fld_org_id'=>$org,
        'fld_suborg_id'=>$suborg,
        'fld_desg_id'=>$desg,
    );

    $profession = array_filter($profession,function($flds){
        foreach($flds as $fld){
            if($fld !== ''){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

}


print_r($profession);
```